# how to map a software as a Drive?

Tags: windows, winapi, drive-mapping

I am trying to create a software like Ibackup.com.  However, I am not sure how to make the software so that it'll map as a local Harddrive.  And i am not sure where to start researching on this.  Someone please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you to [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) ( a user filesystem for windows like FUSE on linux), You install the driver then write the appropriate software for replying on IO request.

On a more complex answer you have to work with the NT DDK to write a driver that would be your software for being a filesystem (look at IFS: installable file system ), note that it is very complicated to work with (mainly because a crash of your software mean a BSOD ), and you would probably like some more higher level software like Dokan that would help you in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a device driver implementing an Installable Filesystem (IFS).

I personally haven't done this but here's a piece of software I know that mounts Linux (ext2/3/4) filesystem on Windows: [Ext2IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

And here's the SDK from Microsoft: [IFS Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/ifskit/default.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Subst](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) command. I suggest you invoke it externally instead of simulating what it does, simply because of all the things that can go wrong.

(Side note: The correct term is a *volume*, not a *drive*.)

Answer (score -1):

Just as a reference: virtual drives can be created using our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) product, which is a supported, documented and maintained solution.

Comment: Yes, but they are WAY too expensive. $2500 for their license @.@

Comment: @Erwin well, you can have the bugs for free of course. But your existing competitors (those who were unlucky to choose free bugs) are migrating to CBFS now.